# umbraco rolls back version of page automatically

Tags: version, umbraco

I have used this site many times in the past, but this is the first time I post a question here.

I have an Umbraco project. Everything normally works great. When I make changes to the content of a page, the changes show up just as they are supposed to. But whenever I restart the site in WebMatrix, the contents of the pages roll back to earlier versions, no matter how much I save the newer versions.

The strangest part is that even when I erase all cookies in the browser, the newer changes can be seen on the site, but in the Content tab the old texts and settings are there instead (and if I save them again, the old versions are shown on the site).

So, to reiterate: when I log in to the editor view, I am presented with old versions of the content. When I look at the actual site, the new content is still there.

This is really annoying whenever I (or anyone else) need to make any changes to the content, since I then need to copy-paste the content from the site, instead of just modifying the text that should already be there.

All help would be deeply appreaciated.

Comment: Hmm... Could it be an issue where the IIS user doesn't have permission to write to the App_Data folder (where content is cached)?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are clicking Save + Publish after making the changes? Does it give a success message or tell you it's failed? If these don't work, please could you post your log entry from App_Data/Logs/ (after clearing it out - just paste the bit written when you publish).  We'll help you then.